# What is the font used?

Tags: fonts

What is the font used in this latex document?
[image: A Latex Document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried looking under File -> Properties -> Fonts?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: We don't really have the resolution to be sure on the body text/equations (e.g. the lineweights are all the same).  Zooming in a little and using the "snapshot" tool in adobe reader might help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the screenshot, the fonts used are the standard LaTeX fonts, i.e., Computer Modern (Roman, Boldface, and Italic; together with the standard LaTeX math fonts). They look like 300dpi pixel fonts (300dpi was a de facto standard resolution of laser printers for a long time in the past).